# validate controls in div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form in html. There are three steps in the form. I want to validate controls of step when user will click on next button. If step is not valid then i want to force user to fill information of first step to go to next using jquery validation.

Please give me idea to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tutorials about form validation with jQuery around the internet. A simple Google Query should give you enough information about how to do this.

The usual process is to just trigger the validation on the .submit process of the form. Then you iterate through the fields and validate that they're not empty and they comply with a set of rules. If everything is alright return true and submit, if something is wrong return false and display a notification.

[Here you go a example.](http://corpocrat.com/2009/07/15/quick-easy-form-validation-tutorial-with-jquery/)

Comment: I want to use jQueryValidation plug in for this and want to validate not on submit button but on link.

Comment: It's the same process. I suggest you do some research ;)